# mail sender not working

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am trying to send auto generated password through gmail to users but It is not working.
I have tried searching on many forums, this is the code I am using. Almost same given on every forum, still not working.

```
using System;
using System.Data;
using System.Configuration;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Security;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.HtmlControls;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls.WebParts;    
using System.Xml.Linq;    
using System.IO;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Mail;    

/// <summary>
/// Summary description for GmailSender
/// </summary>
public class GmailSender
{
    public GmailSender()
    {
        //
        // TODO: Add constructor logic here
        //
    }
    public static bool SendMail(string gMailAccount, string password, string to, string subject, string message)
    {
        try
        {
            NetworkCredential loginInfo = new NetworkCredential("mymail@gmail.com", "mypassword");
            MailMessage msg = new MailMessage();
            msg.From = new MailAddress("mymail@gmail.com");
            msg.To.Add(new MailAddress(to));
            msg.Subject = subject;
            msg.Body = message;
            msg.IsBodyHtml = true;    

            SmtpClient client = new SmtpClient("smtp.gmail.com");
            client.EnableSsl = true;
            client.UseDefaultCredentials = false;
            client.Credentials = loginInfo;
            client.Send(msg);

            return true;
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

Can anyone help me out with this?

Comment: Do you get exceptions in the catch?

Comment: "Not working" is not really enough to go on.  Please describe the behavior in more detail.

Comment: Try add client.Port = 587;

Comment: Not working means it should send mail to user but user is not receiving any mails.

Comment: Are you sure that it doesn't throw any error ? When you return false in catch statement you won't see any error until you debug it.

Comment: @AllanS.Hansen: No I don't get any exceptions.

Comment: @mateuszmcz: Tried adding it, still not working.

Comment: @mateuszmcz: I am directly running it on server so...

Comment: So coment return false in catch statement and change catch (Exception) on catch (Exception e) and add throw e; in change statement. After that run it on server.

Comment: @user3498140 Have you configured `mymail@gmail.com` for `SMTP`?

Comment: @Bharadwaj: How to do that? I don't know

Comment: @user3498140 Check this link -> https://support.google.com/mail/answer/78775?hl=en

Comment: @Bharadwaj:Is there any step by step procedure video or forum link for it?

Comment: @user3498140 Login to gmail account in browser -> go to settings -> in "Forwarding and POP/IMAP" tab -> Enable IMAP Access. Try this and let me know the  result :)

Answer (score 0):

try this (for gmail smtp server).

```
SmtpClient client = new SmtpClient("smtp.gmail.com", 587);
```

Comment: i tried run your code and it works fine to me. maybe review your account and also, try to set the MailMessage.sender.

Comment: Did you do any settings in gmail?

Answer (score 0):

Two day's ago I also had a similar problem. My web app just can't send mails throught gmail account, despite of correct port and credentials.

What helped me was to open my server through RDP and open this address:  http://www.google.com/accounts/DisplayUnlockCaptcha

Here is some more info:
https://support.google.com/mail/answer/14257?hl=en